# Automatic send Notification triggers in every button clicks

Tags: android, firebase

I'm currrently working with an android app that provides news, announcements and events updates.

Now I want to send notifications to all app users that there is a new announcement and when they click it they will go to announcement activity.

This is the announcement activity

[image]

This is I add announcement
[image]

What I want to achieve is, every time that the user (the one who create the announcement) click the button which is "Upload" it will trigger the app to send notification to all the users of my app. if possible I want it to be automatic no need to go to firebase but if it is impossible I'm okay with anything.

I just need an idea how to make it so I will follow but I would be so happy if someone could provide a sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this on the server side. The service that saves the announcement in the data base, can also send an FCM notification to a topic.

You can use the FCM HTTP V1 API to send notifications.

Comment: Okay Thank you! I'll try it